# Access GeoJSON feature keys using Python

Tags: python, geojson

I have a GeoJSON containing thousands of features. It takes the form of:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "uuid": "68F15C01-20CD-4D77-954B-9483BA1D4D33",
            "name": "ABC",
            "len": "529",
            "infotype": "Restricted",
            "h1": null,
            "join": null
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [-360909.60698310119, 7600968.922204642, 0.0],
                [-361357.344715965, 7600811.951385159, 0.0],
                [-361805.08159795138, 7600654.939420643, 0.0]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I'd like to access the keys in properties - `uuid`, `name`, `len`, `infotype`, `h1` and `join`.

I've tried - Example 1 which returns `keys ['type', 'features']`

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

for i in range(len(data['features'])):
    keys = [title.lower() for title in data]
    print('keys', keys)
```

AND I have tried - Example 2 which returns `for i in range(len(data['features']['properties'])): TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

for i in range(len(data['features']['properties'])):
    keys = [title.lower() for title in data]
    print('keys', keys)
```

How can I get the keys to be that of those contained in properties?

Answer (score 7):

(1) In Example 1, it is normal you to get `keys ['type', 'features']` because `title` in `for title in data` gives you a key of `data`.

(2) `data["features"]` is a list and you have to specify index of the feature that you want to get its `properties`. For example, `data['features'][0]['properties']` instead of `data['features']['properties']`. Therefore, in Example 2, you get `must be integers` error.

Briefly, you need a script like this:

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open("data.json")

data = json.load(f)

keys = list(data["features"][0]["properties"].keys())

print(keys)

# OUT
# ['uuid', 'name', 'len', 'infotype', 'h1', 'join']
```